# Dropdown menu does not work with cursor in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a dropdown menu on a popover. Using Google Chrome browse it works fine, but when I use Firefox browser, I cant select a option in the dropdown menu.

Have anyone already faced this issue?

Comment: By dropdown menu, do you mean a `<select>` element? If not, there's no such thing as a universal dropdown menu where other people would experience this same bug. Either way, we need to see some code to be able to help.

Comment: Yes, I mean <select>.

Comment: Right, but where is the code so we can reproduce the problem? Can you recreate it on a JSFiddle for us to see?